# ¿Como firmar un XML en Java android?

Tags: java, android, xml, openssl, signature

Hola amigos antes que nada saludos y espero de antemano puedas ayudarme y gracias. Estoy desarrollando una APP nativa para Android, y necesito firmar un fragmento de código XML de la siguiente manera:

Código a firmar:

```
String DD = "<DD>"+
                "<RE>76276528-4</RE>"+
                "<TD>39</TD>"+
                "<F>4</F>"+
                "<FE>2019-07-08</FE>"+
                "<RR>60803000-K</RR>"+
                "<RSR>SERVICIOS DE IMPUESTOS INTERNOS</RSR>"+
                "<MNT>3000</MNT>"+
                "<IT1>item afecto</IT1>"+
                "<CAF version=\"1.0\">"+
                    "<DA>"+
                        "<RE>76276528-4</RE>"+
                        "<RS>SEGUIMIENTO FLOTA Y MOVILES DEL SUR SPA</RS>"+
                        "<TD>39</TD>"+
                        "<RNG>"+
                            "<D>1</D>"+
                            "<H>10</H>"+
                        "</RNG>"+
                        "<FA>2019-06-11</FA>"+
                        "<RSAPK>"+
                            "<M>9UWD5r656uVPfWPTs3MO4H7/VZWvSSv6A9yHa6tjn3rMG9SZrup9j8ZGFEXhGMMTndhfSNV90hiI7/ow+4KnGQ==</M>"+
                            "<E>Aw==</E>"+
                        "</RSAPK>"+
                        "<IDK>100</IDK>"+
                    "</DA>"+
                    "<FRMA algoritmo=\"SHA1withRSA\">DAFebOnp30toKzDzqNJwDaOOnug0dH4M0l0RvzbEzpt0v0wR8KXDPtcVoF1vAFGTk/gHCthhWrcuc+HnWhSuWA==</FRMA>"+
                "</CAF>"+
                "<TSTED>2019-07-08T15:14:41</TSTED>"+
            "</DD>";
```

Y aquí tengo el RSA PRIVATE KEY:

```
String RSASK = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
"MIIBOwIBAAJBAPgFg+a+uerlT31j07NzDuB+/1WVr0kr+gPch2urY596zBvUma1q\n" +
"fY/GRhRF4RjDE53YX0jVfdIYiO/6MPuCpxkCBQMCQQCjg61EfyacmN+o7TfM912A\n" +
"VKo5DnTbcqatPa+dHO0U+zn3iJZ88Y6ggU2/cTKu8eUHe9qRHeBSjLY2NoXaZAyL\n" +
"AiEA+zZB05bK/hlPSfBH/3JLgCdzxxOLmr45vLqnR1YLrj0CIQD58kXkXLUphbUH\n" +
"hNoVoAy76yrQW51SmAu65AEg2eDmDQIhAKd5gTe53KlmNNv1hVT23QAaTS9iXRHU\n" +
"Jn3RxNo5XR7TAiEEpqGD7ZMjcQPOBQM8DmqzJ/Iciue+DGVdJ0Kraz6V7rMCIQD6\n" +
"4xcKSVJ6ZoGmYrCYv3ltoI36+zW8qieuT4/zuBodow==\n" +
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

En PHP lo logré hacer con open_ssl pero en Java no se como hacerlo, así lo hice en PHP:

```
openssl_sign($DD, $timbre, $Folios->getPrivateKey(), OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)
$timbre = base64_encode($timbre);
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Agregue una respuesta, pero te quiero comentar que RSASK en realidad no parece una real PrivateKey, asegura que esa cadena en verdad sea una PrivateKey, saludos.

Comment: Pero ese es el string que me genera automaticamente el sistema de exportación, lo único que le cambié algunos caracteres del string por medidas de seguridad.

Comment: " lo único que le cambié algunos caracteres del string por medidas de seguridad", no debes modificar el valor string del PrivateKey ya que si lo haces no podrá firmar correctamente el documento.

Comment: Si tengo claro eso, no puede tener nada cambiado. Solo lo hice por medidas de seguridad para poder publicarlo acá.

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto 2 métodos:

**convierte String a PrivateKey**:

```
public static PrivateKey convertStringToPrivateKey(String stringKey){

    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    byte[] sigBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        sigBytes = Base64.decode(stringKey.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        privateKey = keyFact.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);  //throws exception

    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "InvalidKeySpecException signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return privateKey;

}
```

**firma un documento mediante una PrivateKey**:

```
  public static String signDocument(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Aplicado a tu código para obtener el documento firmado:

```
   String signedDocument = null;
    try {
        signedDocument = signDocument(DD, convertStringToPrivateKey(RSASK));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Me arrojó este error:
https://ibb.co/Kz2TJ11

Comment: Probé cambiando el Private Key por un que tengo en un archivo .pem y me funcionó, pero resulta que necesito timbrar el XML con ese RSASK porque así lo está haciendo la librería de PHP que estoy utilizando.

Comment: Creo que el formato de Private Key que se esta usando es Base64